# Get category same as admin category positions position

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the order of specific categories using a php script. The script below runs fine, and I'm seeing the position change values in catalog_category_entity, but order is unaffected in the admin, and in the front.

Answer (score 2):

Please use drag and drop from admin 
And reindex than flush cache

Comment: thanks for rpl but i am get category from collection but its not show in proper order same as admin such as i have three category fight,fitness and fession

Comment: thanks for rpl but i am get category from collection but its not show in proper order same as admin such as i have three category fight,fitness and fashion but when i get from collection its display fight,fashion and fitness actually i am want to get fight,fitness and fashion

Answer (score 1):

are you using your script like this ?

```
<?php
    $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories();
?>

<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category) : ?>
        <li class="<?php if($_category->getId() == $this->getCurrentCategoryId()) echo "active"; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $linkcot; ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></a>
        </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

if not use it like this.